# Aligning drawableLeft with text of button

Tags: android, android-layout

Here is my layout:

[image]

The issue I'm facing is with the drawable checkmark. How would I go about aligning it next to the text, both of them centered within the button? Here is the XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".PostAssignmentActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_checkmark_holo_light"
            android:text="Post" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Cancel" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Applying android:gravity="center_vertical" pulls the text and drawable together, but then the text is no longer aligned in the center.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

### Solution 1

Set `android:paddingLeft` inside your first button. This will force the `drawableLeft` by `paddingLeft` amount to the right. This is the fast/hacky solution.

### Solution 2

Instead of using a ButtonView, use a LinearLayout that contains both a textview and imageview. This is a **better solution**. It gives you more flexibility in the positioning of the checkmark.

Replace your ButtonView with the following code. You need the `LinearLayout` and `TextView` to use `buttonBarButtonStyle` so that the background colors are correct on selection and the text size is correct. You need to set `android:background="#0000"` for the children, so that only the LinearLayout handles the background coloring.

```
<LinearLayout
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <ImageView 
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:background="#0000"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_checkmark_holo_light"/>
    <TextView
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:clickable="false"
        android:background="#0000"
        android:text="Done" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here are some screenshots I took while trying this out.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Having deep view hierarchies with nested LinearLayouts is a bad idea for performance reasons inside ListViews. I don't think it should be a concern here.

Comment: Thanks for doing a writeup this detailed! :)

Comment: This is bad solution for performance and code readability reasons. Using paddings is a way better solution to go with and, if it's not enough, you may consider extending Button view and drawing icon with Canvas and onDraw() method.

Comment: Pawla, you reiterate a good point. If your layout contains a lot of buttons (perhaps inside a ListView), my Solution #1 doesn't handle your design and you are experiencing performance problems: you might want to override Button in order to minimize the number of Views in your hierarchy. But be careful to test this in a RTL layout.

Comment: Did you forget to set the gravity to be centralized in the `LinearLayout`?

Answer (score 37):

None of these solutions worked correctly without presenting unacceptable trade-offs (create a layout with views in it? Not a good idea). So why not roll your own? This is what I got:

[image]

First create an `attrs.xml` with this:

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="IconButton">
        <attr name="iconSrc" format="reference" />
        <attr name="iconSize" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="iconPadding" format="dimension" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

This allows to create an icon with specific size, padding from text, and image in our new view. The view code looks like this:

```
public class IconButton extends Button {
    private Bitmap mIcon;
    private Paint mPaint;
    private Rect mSrcRect;
    private int mIconPadding;
    private int mIconSize;

    public IconButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    public IconButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    public IconButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int shift = (mIconSize + mIconPadding) / 2;

        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(shift, 0);

        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (mIcon != null) {
            float textWidth = getPaint().measureText((String)getText());
            int left = (int)((getWidth() / 2f) - (textWidth / 2f) - mIconSize - mIconPadding);
            int top = getHeight()/2 - mIconSize/2;

            Rect destRect = new Rect(left, top, left + mIconSize, top + mIconSize);
            canvas.drawBitmap(mIcon, mSrcRect, destRect, mPaint);
        }

        canvas.restore();
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        TypedArray array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.IconButton);

        for (int i = 0; i < array.getIndexCount(); ++i) {
            int attr = array.getIndex(i);
            switch (attr) {
                case R.styleable.IconButton_iconSrc:
                    mIcon = drawableToBitmap(array.getDrawable(attr));
                    break;
                case R.styleable.IconButton_iconPadding:
                    mIconPadding = array.getDimensionPixelSize(attr, 0);
                    break;
                case R.styleable.IconButton_iconSize:
                    mIconSize = array.getDimensionPixelSize(attr, 0);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        array.recycle();

        //If we didn't supply an icon in the XML
        if(mIcon != null){
            mPaint = new Paint();
            mSrcRect = new Rect(0, 0, mIcon.getWidth(), mIcon.getHeight());
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap (Drawable drawable) {
        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            return ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        drawable.draw(canvas);

        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

And then it can be used like this:

```
<com.example.grennis.myapplication.IconButton
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:text="Delete"
    app:iconSrc="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
    app:iconSize="32dp"
    app:iconPadding="6dp" />
```

This works for me.

Comment: Take care using measureText() on Android 5 lollipop it will draw the button text ALL CAPS, but measureText() will return the string as it's defined in xml. Use explicit all caps to fix this.

Comment: this is the best solution for me because I didn't have to reproduce the nice effects material design buttons had by default

Comment: Great solution except there's a bug imo. The image and the text aren't centered. To center you need to move the  canvas.restore(); right behind the super.onDraw(canvas);

Comment: How would you handle buttons that set their width to match_parent or wrap_content?  I'm assuming you have to override onMeasure

Comment: @GregEnnis What do you mean with `Use explicit all caps to fix this`? Can you please provide an example?

Comment: Creating custom view class instead of just build right XML layout is an unacceptable trade-off.

Answer (score 28):

You can use 
`<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton/>` .
https://material.io/develop/android/components/material-button/

It finally allows setting the icon gravity.

```
 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Awesome button"
        app:icon="@drawable/your_icon"
        app:iconGravity="textStart" />
```

Comment: It's better solution than else

Comment: Couldn't make it work on Android 19. Icon didn't display

Answer (score 19):

Here is a clean easy way, without doing anything fancy, to achieve the results of having a Button that is much wider than the content with Image and Text which are centered.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background_selector">

    <Button
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="New User"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:id="@android:id/button1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:drawablePadding="6dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/add_round_border_32x32"
        android:layout_height="64dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: This is the easiest solution to create this type of buttons.

Comment: Terrible way using RelativeLayout, don't do this.

Comment: Nesting a standard Checkbox within a RelativeLayout worked great for me.  The button image was biased left, the text was a variable distance away depending on the size of the parent / screen size... nesting within a RelativeLayout normalized the size of the checkbox ( where the button and text looked fine ) and allowed the two to be centered.

Comment: the downside to this is much of what looks like a button is not tappable. And if your button has state changes on press/etc it'll look strange.

Comment: For me, this was by far most useful piece: "
android:drawablePadding="6dp"  Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

In our case, we wanted to use the default Button class (to inherit its various styles and behaviors) and we needed to be able to create the button in code.  Also, in our case we could have text, an icon (left drawable), or both.

The goal was to center the icon and/or text as a group when the button width was wider than wrap_content.

```
public class CenteredButton extends Button
{
    public CenteredButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        // We always want our icon and/or text grouped and centered.  We have to left align the text to
        // the (possible) left drawable in order to then be able to center them in our onDraw() below.
        //
        setGravity(Gravity.LEFT|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        // We want the icon and/or text grouped together and centered as a group.

        // We need to accommodate any existing padding
        //
        float buttonContentWidth = getWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();

        // In later versions of Android, an "all caps" transform is applied to buttons.  We need to get
        // the transformed text in order to measure it.
        //
        TransformationMethod method = getTransformationMethod();
        String buttonText = ((method != null) ? method.getTransformation(getText(), this) : getText()).toString();
        float textWidth = getPaint().measureText(buttonText);

        // Compute left drawable width, if any
        //
        Drawable[] drawables = getCompoundDrawables();
        Drawable drawableLeft = drawables[0];
        int drawableWidth = (drawableLeft != null) ? drawableLeft.getIntrinsicWidth() : 0;

        // We only count the drawable padding if there is both an icon and text
        //
        int drawablePadding = ((textWidth > 0) && (drawableLeft != null)) ? getCompoundDrawablePadding() : 0;

        // Adjust contents to center
        //
        float bodyWidth = textWidth + drawableWidth + drawablePadding;
        canvas.translate((buttonContentWidth - bodyWidth) / 2, 0);

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this solution because it rendered my drawable tint correctly. However, I wanted the text centered with the icon to the left, while this code centers the icon+text. I replaced the translate with the values from Greg's IconButton example so it would work: 
    int left = (int)((getWidth() / 2f) - (textWidth / 2f) - drawableWidth - drawablePadding);
    canvas.translate(left, 0);

Comment: Thanks for the code. In order to have Tint using compat library, I have extended `AppCompatButton` instead of regular Button

Comment: This is by far the best solution IMO! Requires only one class with very few code, and also uses the existing android attributes for compound drawables.

Comment: I'd like to add though that to make this work consistently, you must set gravity in your button like the following: android:gravity="left|center_vertical". This is because gravity defaults to "center" for buttons, and this class also centers the button's content, resulting in an unexpected result.

Answer (score 9):

Here is my code and working perfect.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/green_btn_selector"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="50dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/plus"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    android:text="@string/create_iou"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

Comment: Buttons are also better for accessibility reasons.  Users using the accessibility features don't know they're supposed to press a LinearLayout with an ImageView and TextView inside of it.

Comment: +1 for `android:drawablePadding` works perfectly
@CliveJefferies it works for sizes `wrap content`

Answer (score 3):

```
public class DrawableCenterTextView extends TextView {

    public DrawableCenterTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public DrawableCenterTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public DrawableCenterTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Drawable[] drawables = getCompoundDrawables();
        if (drawables != null) {
            Drawable drawableLeft = drawables[0];
            Drawable drawableRight = drawables[2];
            if (drawableLeft != null || drawableRight != null) {
                float textWidth = getPaint().measureText(getText().toString());
                int drawablePadding = getCompoundDrawablePadding();
                int drawableWidth = 0;
                if (drawableLeft != null)
                    drawableWidth = drawableLeft.getIntrinsicWidth();
                else if (drawableRight != null) {
                    drawableWidth = drawableRight.getIntrinsicWidth();
                }
                float bodyWidth = textWidth + drawableWidth + drawablePadding;
                canvas.translate((getWidth() - bodyWidth) / 2, 0);
            }
        }
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is now available in the [Material Button](https://material.io/develop/android/components/material-button/) by default with the `app:iconGravity` property. However, the [Material Button](https://material.io/develop/android/components/material-button/) does not allow for setting the background to a drawable (RIP gradients).

I converted the answers by [@BobDickinson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37515115/1837367) and [@David-Medenjak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39568381/2461717) above to kotlin and it works great.

```
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.Gravity
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
import kotlin.math.max

class CenteredButton @JvmOverloads constructor(
  context: Context,
  attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
  defStyle: Int = R.attr.buttonStyle
) : AppCompatButton(context, attrs, defStyle) {

  init {
    gravity = Gravity.LEFT or Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL
  }

  override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    val buttonContentWidth = (width - paddingLeft - paddingRight).toFloat()

    var textWidth = 0f
    layout?.let {
      for (i in 0 until layout.lineCount) {
        textWidth = max(textWidth, layout.getLineRight(i))
      }
    }

    val drawableLeft = compoundDrawables[0]
    val drawableWidth = drawableLeft?.intrinsicWidth ?: 0
    val drawablePadding = if (textWidth > 0 && drawableLeft != null) compoundDrawablePadding else 0

    val bodyWidth = textWidth + drawableWidth.toFloat() + drawablePadding.toFloat()

    canvas.save()
    canvas.translate((buttonContentWidth - bodyWidth) / 2, 0f)
    super.onDraw(canvas)
    canvas.restore()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a bit late, but if anyone looking for another answer, here is another way to add icon without the need to wrap button with a ViewGroup

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCamera"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click!"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

*need to set textAllCaps to false to make the spannable working

---

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val buttonLabelBuilder = SpannableStringBuilder(btnCamera.text)
        val iconDrawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_camera)
        iconDrawable?.setBounds(0, 0, btnCamera.lineHeight, btnCamera.lineHeight)
        val imageSpan = ImageSpan(iconDrawable, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM)

        buttonLabelBuilder.insert(0, "i ")
        buttonLabelBuilder.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)

        btnCamera.text = buttonLabelBuilder
    }
}
```

---

[image: button with imagespan]

Answer (score 1):

I started with [@BobDickinson's  answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37515115/1837367), but it did not cope well with multiple lines. The approach is good, because you still end up with a `Button` that can properly be reused.

Here is an adapted solution that will also work if the button has multiple lines (Please don't ask why.)

Just extend `Button` and use the following in `onDraw`, the `getLineRight()` is used to look up the actual length of each line.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // We want the icon and/or text grouped together and centered as a group.
    // We need to accommodate any existing padding
    final float buttonContentWidth = getWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();

    float textWidth = 0f;
    final Layout layout = getLayout();
    if (layout != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < layout.getLineCount(); i++) {
            textWidth = Math.max(textWidth, layout.getLineRight(i));
        }
    }

    // Compute left drawable width, if any
    Drawable[] drawables = getCompoundDrawables();
    Drawable drawableLeft = drawables[0];
    int drawableWidth = (drawableLeft != null) ? drawableLeft.getIntrinsicWidth() : 0;

    // We only count the drawable padding if there is both an icon and text
    int drawablePadding = ((textWidth > 0) && (drawableLeft != null)) ? getCompoundDrawablePadding() : 0;

    // Adjust contents to center
    float bodyWidth = textWidth + drawableWidth + drawablePadding;

    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate((buttonContentWidth - bodyWidth) / 2, 0);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a another solution:

```
     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        style="@style/button_celeste"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            style="@style/button_celeste"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_phone"
            android:text="@string/call_runid"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

and the event:

```
    LinearLayout btnCall = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llButton);
    btnCall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            call(runid.Phone);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I've come up with a solution that doesn't require XML changes or custom Views.

This code snippet retrieves the width of the text and the left/right drawables, and sets the Button's left/right padding so there will only be enough space to draw the text and the drawables, and no more padding will be added.
This can be applied to Buttons as well as TextViews, their superclasses.

```
public class TextViewUtils {
    private static final int[] LEFT_RIGHT_DRAWABLES = new int[]{0, 2};

    public static void setPaddingForCompoundDrawableNextToText(final TextView textView) {
        ViewTreeObserver vto = textView.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                shinkRoomForHorizontalSpace(textView);
            }
        });

    }

    private static void shinkRoomForHorizontalSpace(TextView textView) {
        int textWidth = getTextWidth(textView);
        int sideCompoundDrawablesWidth = getSideCompoundDrawablesWidth(textView);
        int contentWidth = textWidth + sideCompoundDrawablesWidth;
        int innerWidth = getInnerWidth(textView);
        int totalPadding = innerWidth - contentWidth;
        textView.setPadding(totalPadding / 2, 0, totalPadding / 2, 0);
    }

    private static int getTextWidth(TextView textView) {
        String text = textView.getText().toString();
        Paint textPaint = textView.getPaint();
        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        textPaint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
        return bounds.width();
    }

    private static int getSideCompoundDrawablesWidth(TextView textView) {
        int sideCompoundDrawablesWidth = 0;
        Drawable[] drawables = textView.getCompoundDrawables();
        for (int drawableIndex : LEFT_RIGHT_DRAWABLES) {
            Drawable drawable = drawables[drawableIndex];
            if (drawable == null)
                continue;
            int width = drawable.getBounds().width();
            sideCompoundDrawablesWidth += width;
        }
        return sideCompoundDrawablesWidth;
    }

    private static int getInnerWidth(TextView textView) {
        Rect backgroundPadding = new Rect();
        textView.getBackground().getPadding(backgroundPadding);
        return textView.getWidth() - backgroundPadding.left - backgroundPadding.right;
    }
}
```

Notice that:

- It actually still leaves some more space than needed (good enough for my purposes, but you may look for the error)
- It overwrites whatever left/right padding is there. I guess it's not difficult to fix that.

To use it, just call `TextViewUtils.setPaddingForCompoundDrawableNextToText(button)` on your `onCreate` or `onViewCreated()`.

Comment: Haven't tried something like this for long time, but back in times of 2.x, 4.x, 5.x and 6.x API each did evaluate the pixel sizes of text differently, I never managed to get a universally working code across all desired versions of Android, especially 5.x vs 6.x was completely different IIRC, including some internal bugs in implementation of those functions... If you did some extensive testing across common APIs today, it would be helpful to specify that in your answer, that you know it works well.

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions to this problem. Perhaps the easiest on some devices is to use `paddingRight` and `paddingLeft` to move the image and text next to each other as below.

### Original button

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/scan_qr_code"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_camera"
    android:paddingRight="90dp"
    android:paddingLeft="90dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
```

[image: Using Padding can work]

The problem here is on smaller devices this padding can cause unfortunate problems such as this:
[image]

The other solutions are all some version of "build a button out of a layout an image and a textview". They work, but completely emulating a button can be tricky. I propose one more solution; "build a button out of a layout an image, a textview, *and a button*"

Here's the same button rendered as I propose:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/scanQR"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/white_bg_button"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/scanImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_camera"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button"
            android:text="@string/scan_qr_code"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see, the button is now within a relative layout, but it's text and drawableLeft are not part of the button, they are in a separate layout that's placed on top of the button. With this, the button still acts like a button. The gotchas are:

1. The inner layout needs an elevation for newer versions of Android. The button itself has an elevation greater than the ImageView and TextView, so even though they are defined *after* the Button, they will still be "below" it in elevation and be invisible. Setting 'android:elevation' to 10 solves this.
2. The textAppearance of the TextView must be set so that it has the same appearance as it would in a button.

Answer (score -4):

Another quite hacky alternative is to add blank spacer views with `weight="1"` on each side of the buttons. I don't know how this would affect performance.

```
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible, you can't add elements inside a button

Comment: You would put the spacer views either side of the button not within the button. It centers the button's text and drawable. The spacer regions are not a clickable part of the button. This technique could also be used making the containing layout clickable. It's not a great solution but it may be suitable for some people.