# How to display 3 buttons (text + icons centered)

Tags: java, android

How to display 3 buttons (text + icons centered) equidistant on screen horizontally ?

Here is my code.
This method works but the icon is not centered

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:layout_below="@id/message">
<Button android:id="@+id/action_like"
    android:text="Like"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#104e75"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_like" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/action_comment"
    android:text="Comment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#104e75"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_comment" />
<Button 3 ....>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Aligning drawableLeft with text of button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14668219/aligning-drawableleft-with-text-of-button)

Comment: yes....i know that post, but I'm looking for a different method of setting the paddingLeft when the width is not fixed (it's variable)

Comment: There are two solutions mentioned in the accepted answer in that post, although it seems that the author forgot to specify central gravity.